# how to convert the type of a column out of a orm into a graphql type?

Tags: typescript, metadata, typeorm, graphql-js, converters

How can i take the type I get from a column and turn it into a GraphQL type?
For instance the type String into a GraphQLString, Number into a GraphQLString, etc

the value example I have:

```
firstName: { type: [Function: String] },
```

Do I have to map the value of the column with a GraphQL value?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.. added the @Field decorator to the model column def...

```
  @Field(() => String)
  @Column("char", { name: "remarks", nullable: true, length: 31 })
  remarks: string | null;
```

with an import from

```
import {Field, Int, ObjectType} from "type-graphql";
```